# .NET Core - Confirming asset has been included with production build

Tags: c#, .net, email, dev-to-production

I've got a .NET Core Web API Solution with multiple projects, I'll post the structure below and the paths where necessary.

I have an Email Service that pulls a template from a path in the same project, parses it and sends it via Email.

```
Solution -
   Core (Project Models, Context and Interfaces)
   MainProject (Executed Project) -
      Controllers -
          EmailController.cs
   Repository
   Services -
      Email -
         templates -
            ContactEmailTemplate.html
         EmailService.cs
```

The email service looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Core.Email.Services;
using Core.Email.Services.Models;
using Core.Services.Response;

namespace Services.Email
{
    public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {
        private const string SmtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
        private const int PortNumber = 587;
        private const bool EnableSsl = true;
        private const string EmailFromAddress = ""; //Sender Email Address  
        private const string Password = ""; //Sender Password  
        private const string EmailToAddress = ""; //Receiver Email Address  
        private const string Subject = "New Email From...";

        public ServicesResponse<bool> SendEmail(EmailRequest emailRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var mail = CreateMailMessage(emailRequest);
                
                using var smtp = new SmtpClient(SmtpAddress, PortNumber);
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailFromAddress, Password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = EnableSsl;
                smtp.Send(mail);

                return new ServicesResponse<bool>
                {
                    Data = true,
                    Exception = null,
                    HasError = false
                };   
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return ServicesResponse<bool>.FromException(exception);
            }
        }

        private static MailMessage CreateMailMessage(EmailRequest request)
        {
            return new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(EmailFromAddress),
                To = { EmailToAddress },
                Body = CreateMailMessageFromHtml(request),
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Subject = Subject
            };
        }

        private static string CreateMailMessageFromHtml(EmailRequest request)
        {
            string body;
            
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "../../../../Services/Email/templates/ContactEmailTemplate.html"))) /* <--- Is this even going to work in prod?  */
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            body = body.Replace("{Name}", request.Name);
            body = body.Replace("{Message}", request.Message);

            return body;
        }
    }
```

And it all works fine, I've seen the email in my inbox on a debug build. I don't feel very confident about this piece of code at all though however:

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "../../../../Services/Email/templates/ContactEmailTemplate.html"))) /* <--- Is this even going to work in prod?  */
```

I'm worried that as soon as this goes into a production build it's going to blow up, it feels quite dirty.

How can I confirm that an asset like ContactEmailTemplate.html is included in the production build?

Will it be Included in the `.dll` bundle for the `Services` project?

EDIT: I've added ContactEmailTemplate.html as an embedded resource to the project and refactored `CreateMailMessageFromHtml` to the following

```cs
 private static string CreateMailMessageFromHtml(EmailRequest request)
        {
            string body;
            var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
// tried the following to get the template
            var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmbeddedResource/Email/templates/ContactEmailTemplate.html");
var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmbeddedResource.Email.templates.ContactEmailTemplate.html");
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Email\\templates\\ContactEmailTemplate.html");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            body = body.Replace("{Name}", request.Name);
            body = body.Replace("{Message}", request.Message);

            return body;
        }
```

But everything returns null when I get to opening the stream

Answer (score 2):

If you add the HTML file to a project and click on the file in the solution explorer, you can see a property called Build Action in the properties window. If you change that to embedded resource, the file will (once compiled) live in the DLL en therefore always be available.

To determine all files delivered as embedded resource (and get the full name of yours)

`var allResourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();`

I have created an example project for you to demonstrate the usage:
https://github.com/nikneem/embedded-resource-example

To open the file through a stream:

`using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))`

Comment: I've added the email template as an embedded resource and it appears to have been added successfully: 

Services.scproj
```<ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Email\templates\ContactEmailTemplate.html" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Email\templates\ContactEmailTemplate.html">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
```

But when I open a new stream with assembly.GetManifestResourceStream I get null returned. I will update my question to show what I've tried

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't work for you? Or is your problem solved. Looking at your code I can see that you use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly which may not be the assembly containing your HTML file. If you use typeof(AnyClassInYourAssembly).Assembly you will get the correct assembly.

Comment: I have updated the answer, it now contains an example project

Comment: I think the problem is solved, however, I'd like to give your suggestion a try and see if that works as I want confidence in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Eduard Keilhoz's answer. I embedded the HTML file, which added this to my `.csproj` file:

```xml
 <ItemGroup>
   <None Remove="Email\templates\ContactEmailTemplate.html" />
   <EmbeddedResource Include="Email\templates\ContactEmailTemplate.html">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

then updated `CreateMailMessageFromHtml` to the following:

```cs
 private static string CreateMailMessageFromHtml(EmailRequest request)
 {
     string body;
     var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Services.Email.templates.ContactEmailTemplate.html") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
     {
         body = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }

     body = body.Replace("{Name}", request.Name);
     body = body.Replace("{Message}", request.Message);

     return body;
 }
```

This is for `.NET Core 5.0` if anyone is interested